# Map, find all maximum

Tags: java

I have map like

Jon 5.5
Susi 10.1
Linda 10.1
Lora 4
Ivan 5
Kevin 10.1

I wanna find and sout name with max value

```
Double max = Collections.max(map.values());
for (String s : map.keySet()){
            if (map.get(s)==max){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
```

and it doesnt work
wtf?

[image]

Comment: I mean, why i cant find all persons with value == 10.1 in my "if" 
pls try this code on ur pc and u will find only Kevin, but Lora and Linda will be ignored

Comment: We can't try this code without writing additional code responsible for filling your map which may be different from what you really have. Take your time and create proper [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Also don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: What does IntelliJ want to tell you at the yellow `==`?

Comment: use `equals` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy. Just use comparatpr for `Map.Entry`:

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Jon", 5.5);
map.put("Susi", 10.1);
map.put("Linda", 10.1);
map.put("Loar", 4.);
map.put("Ivan", 5.);
map.put("Kevin", 10.1);

map.entrySet().stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue().reversed())
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**P.S.** This is **correct** way to compare `double` in `Java`

```
boolean equals = Double.compare(1.1, 2.2) == 0;
```

Comment: boolean equals = Double.compare(d1, d2) == 0;
this is how it works
ty

Answer (score 1):

While I can not reproduce the problem you seem to have with your code (my guess would be that you are not using the map that you think you are using), you can simplify your code and get rid of that `for` loop by just getting the `max` of the `Entry`s in the map, comparing those by their `value`. You can either use `Collections.max` with a special comparator...

```
Entry<String, Double> max = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), 
        Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue));
```

... or use the Java 8 Stream API:

```
Entry<String, Double> max = map.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue)).get();
```

The result is the same, i.e. `Kevin=10.1`. If you want just the name, use `max.getKey()`.